# Get Selected Custom option of a product in a custom page (Magento)

Tags: magento

I am trying to show the products in shopping cart in a panel which is accessible in all pages(in menu). I have accomplished it by using below

```
      $cartHelper = Mage::helper('checkout/cart');
      $items = $cartHelper->getCart()->getItems();
```

but i am struggling with showing the Custom option selected for each product.
I tried using

`$item->getOptionList()`

but its not working for me..

Please give me a hand on this.

Thanks,
Balan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer, below code would print the custom option selected

```
$options = array();
if ($optionIds = $item->getOptionByCode('option_ids')) {
$options = array();
foreach (explode(',', $optionIds->getValue()) as $optionId) {
if ($option = $item->getProduct()->getOptionById($optionId)) {

$quoteItemOption = $item->getOptionByCode('option_' . $option->getId());

$group = $option->groupFactory($option->getType())
->setOption($option)
->setQuoteItemOption($quoteItemOption);

$options[] = array(
'label' => $option->getTitle(),
'value' => $group->getFormattedOptionValue($quoteItemOption->getValue()),
'print_value' => $group->getPrintableOptionValue($quoteItemOption->getValue()),
'option_id' => $option->getId(),
'option_type' => $option->getType(),
'custom_view' => $group->isCustomizedView()
);
}
}
}
if ($addOptions = $item->getOptionByCode('additional_options')) {
$options = array_merge($options, unserialize($addOptions->getValue()));
}
```

thanks goes to http://www.e-commercewebdesign.co.uk see 
[this link](http://www.e-commercewebdesign.co.uk/blog/magento-tutorials/echo-magento-custom-option-values-in-checkout.php) for reference.

Comment: That was fast. I guess most of the time you spent on question post :)
Or it's just commercial?

Comment: Nope.. 
i tried out samples from Google results for a long time.. but as i don't get any result.. i posted in here.. i could able to find the solution as soon as i posted...

Answer (score 0):

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();

foreach ($cart->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {    
$options = Mage::helper('catalog/product_configuration')->getCustomOptions($item);

}
```

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer. It would be helpful than just a piece of code.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.